# Is it possible to create an OData query from a nested SQL query without 'ANY' function?

Tags: sql, odata, azure-logic-apps

I want to convert the below SQL query into OData query. Is it even possible with nested query and without `any` function?

```sql
SELECT distinct mid, iid
FROM test_table
where mid not in (
    SELECT mid
    FROM test_table
    WHERE resp IS NOT NULL
) AND iid not in (
    SELECT iid
    FROM test_table
    WHERE resp IS NOT NULL
)
```

I can't use `any` function because it is not supported by Azure Logic App.

Comment: You should include your OData query attempts

Comment: I would solve this by modifying the API to provide this as a _function_ or in SQL as a _View_ OData is not supposed to enable 100% compatibility with SQL.